# Сортировка экземпляров классов

Tags: c#, сортировка, list

Как можно сортировать такой List по name?

```
class Test{

List<Book> = new List<Book>();

   class Book{
      int id;
      string name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код не компилируется, а поле name объявлено как приватное. Без изменения класса Book никак не отсортировать.

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
list.Sort((b1, b2) => b1.name.CompareTo(b2.name));
```

Или так:

```
list = list.OrderBy(b => b.name).ToList();
```

Это при условии, что вы сделаете поле `name` открытым. И дадите имя вашему списку.

Comment: Ну это понятно) Спасибо!